# Git credential helper causes "repository not found" error?

Tags: git

Just ran into this Git behavior which looks like a bug with credential-store:

```bash
$ git pull
Username for 'https://github.com': ...
Password for 'https://...@github.com': ...
Already up-to-date.
$ git config credential.helper store
$ git pull
remote: Repository not found.
```

Then, go and edit .git/config to remove `[credential] helper = store` and git pull works again.

What could cause it?

How do I use credential helper without running into this error?

**UPDATE** Using git version 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

**UPDATE** Retested with git version 2.9.3, same result.

**UPDATE** I have several accounts on github in ~/.git-credentials. I ran git with GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 and it looks like it picks the first github account in the order they're listed.

However .git/config in the repo I'm working in has the correct user.email, which does have a matching entry in ~/.git-credentials.  It just doesn't use that entry.

Comment: My guess is that you entered bad credentials.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I *didn't* enter credentials!  It never asked me, after credential helper was set.

Comment: What I meant by the comment was that the credentials which you stored have a problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Okay.  Where did it get the credentials from, and where did it store them?  (notice that the credential helper is enabled only after the login, not before)  Why does it say "repository not found", rather than something like "incorrect username or password"?

Comment: "Repository not found" is just what it fails on.  Technically, it makes sense because it could not authenticate you and therefore could not find any repos.

Answer (score 16):

What worked for me was in .git folder I opened the config file.

Now you need to insert:

```
[credential "https://github.com/yourProjectPath"]

username = yourGithubUsername
```

After this you can use:

```
git config credential.helper store
```

This will add this to the config file:

```
[credendial]
helper = store
```

Make sure the config file has this section at the end and does not have a duplicate of it **before** the "credential" section you added previously

Then run:

```
git pull
```

And fill in your password.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu Linux, the first thing to do is to update Git to its latest version through [`git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/%7Egit-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Then check if the issue persists with git 2.9.3.

---

[Arun Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3041943/arun-wilson) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239417/git-credential-helper-causes-repository-not-found-error/39243801#comment111367863_39243801):

> In my case, there were two entries in `~/.git-credentials` against github.com and first one was wrong against from the repo folder that I pulled
>
> ```
> https://username-2:********@github.com    
> https://username-1:********@github.com    
> https://username-1:*********@gitlab.com   
> https://username-1:*********@bitbucket.org
> ```

Comment: @AlexI OK, I have rewritten the answer.

Comment: Upgraded to 2.9.3, results are identical

Comment: I have several accounts at github.  They are all in ~/.git-credentials.  I ran git with GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 and it looks like it picks the *first* github account from ~/.git-credentials.  However .git/config in the repo I'm working in has the correct user.email, which does have a matching entry in ~/.git-credentials.  Bug?

Comment: @AlexI I'm struggling with the same stupid behaviour. I'd call it a bug because both the error message and it ignoring the right email is bad UX and wrong.

Comment: @VonC I'm using 2.15.1

Comment: @Avamander Does the issue persists with Git 2.17? Are you on Ubuntu?

Comment: @VonC I installed git 2.16.2 from the PPA, the issue still persists. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: @Avamander And what is the value of `git config credential.helper`?

Comment: @VonC The output is `store`.

Comment: @Avamander Could you try using libsecret? (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285250/6309)

Comment: @VonC This is the output after setting the `credential.helper` to `libsecret`: `git: 'credential-libsecret' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Username for 'https://github.com': ^C`

Comment: @Ava It is in the contrib folder of Git: add it to your PATH

Comment: @VonC I guess it works, but I don't want to start unlocking my keyring either. The whole point of `store` was that I don't have to enter anything on my own PC.

Comment: In my case, there were two entries in ~/.git-credentials against github.com and first one was wrong against from the repo folder that I pulled

```https://username-2:********@github.com   
https://username-1:********@github.com   
https://username-1:*********@gitlab.com  
https://username-1:*********@bitbucket.org```

Comment: @ArunWilson Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.