# git status: bad filename results in "protocol error"

Tags: git

I have a local copy of a remote git repository. Every time I execute "git status", I get this error:

```
git status
public/app.chart/license/Creative Commons�� Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International�� CC BY-NC-SA 4.0.pdf: Protocol error
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Said file doesn't exist in the repository.
When I switch branches, I get this message:

```
git checkout test_branch 
D   "public/app.chart/license/Creative Commons\200\224 Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International\200\224 CC BY-NC-SA 4.0.pdf"
Switched to branch 'test_branch'
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: It's clear from both `git status` and `git checkout` that this file *does* exist in the repository. It merely does not exist in the *work tree*, presumably because the OS rejects the path name. Are you on MacOS?  What version of Git do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and see if the issue persists after a:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git config core.quotepath false
```

From [`git config` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-corequotePath):

> If this variable is set to false, the bytes higher than 0x80 are not quoted but output as verbatim.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference, but thanks for helping :-)

Comment: @Ledazinha OK. What version of Git are you using? and on which OS?

Comment: Git version is 2.7.4. OS is Ubuntu 16.04 xenial; Kernel is x86_64 Linux 4.4.0-42-generic.

Comment: @Ledazinha Could you try an dupdate to the latest 2.11 (with ppa update as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309)?

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to work... I guess I'll just create a fresh repo. Again, thanks for helping ;-)