# git clone copy-fd Permission denied

Tags: git, ubuntu

When I do:

```
git clone git@192.168.15.11:xxx/xxx.git
```

there is a error:

```
Cloning into 'xxx'...  
error: copy-fd: write returned Permission denied  
fatal: cannot copy '/usr/share/git-core/templates/description' to '/mnt/wk01/xxx/.git/description': Permission denied
```

Who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permission issue might not be in the destination folder `/mnt/wk01/xxx/`, but in the source folder `usr/share/git-core/templates/description`

As [mentioned here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=596066):

> Package: git-core, Version: 1.5.6.5
>
> The file permissions of files placed in /usr/share/git-core/templates
>   are wrong now. They are not readable for everyone, so command "git init"
>   fails with message:

```
fatal: cannot copy /usr/share/git-core/templates/description to ...
```

> `chmod a+r` for all files in templates solves this issue.

Make sure to [upgrade to the latest git version through git-core ppa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309).

Comment: Thanks for your help.