# local git config during remote ssh session

Tags: git, session, ssh, git-config

To be clear, what I'm not asking is how to bring my ssh keys with me along an ssh session. I'm aware that `ssh -A` will do what I want.

However, what I notice is that all global config on the remote machine are being applied to my git commands, so even though my ssh key is being used to git push/pull.

The problem is that when I do commit, the Author string is not me.

So the questions is, **is there any way to bring my global `git config` from my client machine across an ssh session to use on the remote machine?**

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that when I do commit, the Author string is not me.

The ssh session is done as the remote user you are specifyong in your `ssh <remoteUser>@remotemachine>`

Once you are in your remote ssh session, do a ([with Git 2.8+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35670933/6309)):

```
git config -l --show-origin
```

You will see *all* configurations, including from where the `user.name` is coming from.

If you want at least to use the right user.name/email, you would need to specify them in your git commit command:

```
git commit -c user.name=xxx -c user.email=yyy commit -m "my commit"
```

Comment: :/ git version 1.7.1 on the remote machine

Comment: @xaviersjs yes, problably an old Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. You can upgrade Git fairly easily though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309