# Deleted old dir, cloned a new one, and now can't push it remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab

I deleted my current development directory, cloned a new one from my online repository, and now when I try to to do a

> git push origin

I receive a

> error: The requested URL returned error: 401 while accessing https://gitlab.com/..../.....git/info/refs
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

What can be the cause? Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 0):

[401 means](https://httpstatuses.com/401)

> Unauthorized
>
> The request has not been applied because it lacks valid authentication credentials for the target resource.

Check your `git config credential.helper` value: it is possible it caches the wrong credentials (username/password)

Comment: I entered "git config credential.helper" on the command line and nothing happened. Then tried again "git push origin" and the same problem persisted.

Comment: @user2752471 On what OS are you? What is your Git version?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.04, git version is 1.7.0.4

Comment: @user2752471 10.04 as in 2010? (http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.04.0/). Git 1.7.0.4 as in Sept. 2010? (https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.0.4.txt). I didn't know computers existed back then. I wasn't even born yet. Any chance to install Git 2.17 through ppa (as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309)?

Comment: Do you mean typing these commands?                                             sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git             I did the first but I am afraid that if I enter the second command it will star to update everything on m system and not only git. Will it only update git? If not how can I tell apt to update only git?

Comment: Yes , in order to upgrade Git.

Comment: Edited the first comment, please take a look. I mean the one that you just answered to.

Comment: It will list the list it will update. But if this seems too much, update your repo somewhere else, on another machine where got is up-to-date, and then go back to your old Linux, and pull. They way, you avoid the push issue.

Comment: I did a sudo apt-get update and it did printed a lot of messages like: Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release.gpg
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg
Ign http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
........   Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Sources
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Packages
Hit http://old-releases.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages.   Then if I issue a sudo apt install git I receive: sudo: apt: command not found

Comment: It's apt-get, not apt

Comment: I send a "git push origin" and received: "warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use: .........................Username for 'https://gitlab.com':"  Shall I enter my https://gitlab.com/asmf2/asmfrt.git ? Repeating the "https://gitlab.com" part?

Comment: A git config --global push.default simple will fix that

Comment: What you need to enter is your Gottlieb Gitlab username and password, assuming you don't have 2fa (2 factor authentication)

Comment: This is what I tried to do entered: git push -u origin......  Username for 'https://gitlab.com': https://gitlab.com/asmf2/asmfrt.git
Password for 'https://https://gitlab.com/asmf2/asmfrt.git@gitlab.com': 
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/asmf2/asmfrt.git/' I entered my password for the gitlab website. I also tried "git config --global push.default" after that and then repeated all above without success