# Why does git-imap-send seem to be sending HTTP to an IMAP connection?

Tags: git, imap

I hope that I'm not making some blatantly obvious mistake here, but when attempting to use `git imap-send`, in the command `git format-patch --signoff --stdout --attach --root HEAD | git imap-send -v`, I get this (error repeated once for each patch):

```
$ git format-patch --signoff --stdout --attach --root HEAD | git imap- 
send -v
sending 21 messages
*   Trying 192.168.1.22...
* Connected to mail.tdstoragebay.com (192.168.1.22) port 143 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> PUT /INBOX HTTP/1.1
Host: mail.tdstoragebay.com:143
Authorization: Basic auth-token
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 3233
Expect: 100-continue

* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE 
IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] TD-StorageBay Dovecot ready.
PUT BAD Error in IMAP command received by server.
Host: BAD Error in IMAP command received by server.
* BYE Too many invalid IMAP commands.
* Connection #0 to host mail.tdstoragebay.com left intact
* Found bundle for host mail.tdstoragebay.com: 0x1f59250 [serially]
* Connection 0 seems to be dead!
* Closing connection 0
```

It seems to me that `git imap-send` is attempting to send HTTP data to my IMAP server. All the documentation I've read seems says *nothing* about this behavior, and `imap-send` uses normal IMAP. If this is the case, what is going on, and more importantly, how can it be fixed?

Git version: 2.7.4

OS: Linux Mint 18.3

Git configuration:

```
imap.host=imap://mail.tdstoragebay.com (internal server)
imap.port=143
imap.folder=INBOX
```

Comment: Did you check if the error persists with Git 2.18?

Comment: At this point Git 2.18 hasn't been added to the `apt` mirror I'm using, so I haven't been able to get it. Give me one second.

Comment: OK: see for instance https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309

Comment: Already did, didn't think to check for one beforehand, silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have been a few imap-send related fixes since Git 2.7.4

Notably:

- [commit d2d07ab](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d2d07ab8613ef283ceda6fdaa05fa6976dc1206f) "`imap-send`: Tell cURL to use `imap://` or `imaps://`" (Git 2.10.2)
- [commit 690307f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/690307f3d1ae127e0ecb6198aeb44936c8dd9330) "`imap-send`: add wrapper to get server credentials if needed " (Git 2.15.0)

Any of those fixes could have an impact in your case.

---

"[`git imap-send`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/18da62619796c8270f922a49018dbc52635aea23/Documentation/git-imap-send.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-imap-send))</sup> used to ignore configuration variables like core.askpass; this has been corrected with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021),

See [commit 5021236](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50212361d9487ac3005c3041fac0d6b4d999807a) (01 Dec 2020) by [Nicolas Morey-Chaisemartin (`nmorey`)](https://github.com/nmorey).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 18da626](https://github.com/git/git/commit/18da62619796c8270f922a49018dbc52635aea23), 08 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`imap-send`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50212361d9487ac3005c3041fac0d6b4d999807a): parse default git config
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Nicolas Morey-Chaisemartin</sup>

> [`git imap-send git config`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/50212361d9487ac3005c3041fac0d6b4d999807a/Documentation/git-config.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> does not parse the default settings and thus ignore `core.askpass` value.
>
> Rewrite config parsing to support `core` settings.

Answer (score 1):

As of upgrading to Git 2.18, it appears that the error has resolved itself. Though I'm still curious as to why it existed in the first place.