# Expansion of alias failed; not a git command

Tags: git

I must be missing something obvious... but Git aliases are not working at all. Help me please!

```sh
$ git config --global alias.v version
$ git config --global --list
alias.v=version
$ git config --global alias.v
version
$ git v
Expansion of alias 'v' failed; 'version' is not a git command
$ git version
git version 2.9.0
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
        v = version
```

#### Update 1

As per @torek's suggestion, I tested the same thing with `log`, and it also doesn't work:

```sh
$ git config --global alias.l log
$ git config --global --list
alias.v=version
alias.l=log
$ git config --global alias.l
log
$ git l
Expansion of alias 'l' failed; 'log' is not a git command
$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
        v = version
        l = log
```

#### Update 2: Solved

The problem was that `git --exec-path` was somehow set to an incorrect directory. In the end, I built and installed from source and now everything works as expected. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a command other than `version`.  Try aliasing `l` to `log`, for instance.  (Or, as VonC notes, upgrade—it actually *does* work in modern Git.  The alias handling seems to have been rewritten between 2.17.3 and 2.18.0.)

#### Why does `l = log` work, and yet `v = version` not?

This is a little tricky!

Most Git commands are—and at one point, *all* Git commands *were*—separate programs that are installed separately into a directory (or folder, if you prefer the term) full of "Git commands you can run".  For instance, `git log` is actually implemented by a command spelled `git-log`, which is installed in a special directory / folder.

This directory / folder is *not* one you normally run commands *from*, though.

Back in the distant past, these Git commands—`git-log`, `git-commit`, `git-add`, `git-diff`, and so on—were all installed directly, and you ran them directly, by typing in `git-something`.  This worked OK with bash's autocompletion, in that you could type `git-comTAB` to get the commit command, or `git-chTAB` to get the checkout command.  But over time, the number of Git commands grew (`git-cherry` and `git-cherry-pick`), and grew, and grew; and eventually even typing in the full command `git-add` wasn't *enough* because there's also `git-add--interactive` for instance, so the <kbd>TAB</kbd> completion basically completely stopped working.

A decision was made: Git wasn't going to stop coming with 57 different commands—actually, it's over 150 now—but instead, all these various *implementation* commands would be stuffed away into a place where they would not be all up in your face all the time.  A *single front end* command, spelled `git`, would let you type in the command as an *argument* to the front-end `git` command: `git com`, then <kbd>TAB</kbd>: bash now has a *list* of *allowed* completions, and will only pick `commit` since that's the only `com` that *you* would use, not the `git-commit-tree` or `git-commit-graph` back end programs that only scripts regularly use.

So: the *front end* `git` command knows how to find and run all the various *back end* implementations.  By convention, most of them are in the `git-core` directory: run

```
git --exec-path
```

and the front end prints out the name of the place where all the back-end programs actually live.  (You can look in there, and even run them out of there directly if you like, although these days the front end `git` command now sets up information that the back end commands may want.)

But what about `git version`?  Well, now that you know that Git commands actually live in the `git-core` folder, wherever that may be on your system, I suggest you look in there.  Where is the `git-version` program?  You will find `git-checkout` in there, and `git-log`, and `git-commit`, and `git-diff` and many others, but **you won't find a `git-version`.  There isn't one.**

The `version` command is built directly in to the *front end*.  The *aliases* only work when invoking a *back end* command.  So there is—or was, anyway—no way to alias `version`.  (At some point, obviously post 2.9 and pre 2.24, the alias handling code was smartened up to check the front-end built-ins as well.)

#### There's one more important thing to know

The front end `git` command *does* know about some common back end commands, but it *doesn't* have a *complete list* of back end commands.  Instead, when you type in `git asdf` or `git rumplestiltskin` or `git helloworld`—none of which are actual Git commands—it just sets things up as usual and then *attempts* to run `git-asdf` or `git-rumplestiltskin` or `git-helloworld`, while telling the system to look in the `git-core` directory.  It doesn't tell the system *not* to look in *other* directories.

This means *you* can write *your own* Git commands.  If you want a `git asdf`, you can write your own `git-asdf` program, and put it anywhere so that running `git-asdf` succeeds.  You can now run it using `git asdf`.

Why, you might wonder, would you *want* to do this?  If you install `git-asdf` in your own personal bin or scripts folder, you can just run `git-asdf`.  And indeed, you can do that.  But when you have the *front end* run it, you're run with special Git setup information provided.  This gives you the ability to write your program as an sh (or bash) script *and* get direct access to various Git helpers.  The main helper is called `git-sh-setup` and you invoke it by "sourcing" it, with `.` (POSIX) or `source` (bash):

```
#! /bin/sh
. git-sh-setup
```

This adds shell functions `die` and `say` and `git_pager` and `require_clean_work_tree` and more.  If you set the shell variable `OPTIONS_SPEC` before sourcing `git-sh-setup`, it will parse arguments for you.  Look at the script—it's right there in the `git-core` directory—to see how to use it.

(Note that, like all things Git, it has grown over time.  It has more functions now than it did in the days of Git 1.7, for instance.  If you want something that backports to older versions of Git, clone the Git repository for Git, pick a compatibility level, and `git checkout` the old one to see what you can rely on.)

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting and informative answer. Unfortunately, aliasing `log` doesn't work either. Please see "Update 1" in my updated question above.

Comment: What does `git --exec-path` show and what is in the directory shown? (You may have an incorrectly-installed version of Git.)

Comment: Aha! That was the problem. `git --exec-path` reported a different directory to the one where it was installed. I tried setting `GIT_EXEC_PATH` in `.bashrc` but that didn't fix it, so in the end I followed [these instructions](http://joemaller.com/908/how-to-install-git-on-a-shared-host/#comments) to build and install from source in `$HOME/bin`. Now everything works fine. The body of your answer didn't actually fix the problem, but your last comment above did, so I'll mark this answer as accepted. Thanks again, @torek!

Answer (score 9):

You can try putting a `!` at the front of your alias:

```
git config --global alias.git '!git'
```

After doing that you no longer have problems accessing "external" scripts...

This is documented at the bottom of git's page about aliases:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

Answer (score 4):

you can also use,

```sh
$ git config --global alias.v "!git version"
$ git v
git version 2.20.1
```

Comment: That's an okay workaround for now. Thanks. (But I still want to find out why it's not working the normal way.)

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it with Git 2.24 and 2.25.1: it does work just fine.

```
C:\>git config --global alias.v version

C:\>git v
git version 2.25.1.windows.1
```

So first, try and update from the old 2.9.0 to the current 2.25.1, and see if the issue persists.
([ppa upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309) if you are on Linux)

I suspect [commit 50ad856](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50ad8561dee9d479e41586689486cbbb4a742f7b) in Git  v2.14.0-rc0 (Q3 2017) helped.

---

> But this exact same version, installed from the exact same tarball, works fine on another machine. So it seems unlikely that the version of git is the cause?

Then you need to compare the `.bashrc/.profile` as well as the output of `env` between those two machines accounts.
A difference in execution environment might explain the difference.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Due to restrictions around the admin of this machine, I can't easily upgrade the git version. (I will ask the sysadmin for help.) But this exact same version, installed from the exact same tarball, works fine on another machine. So it seems unlikely that the version of git is the cause?

Comment: Thank you. In the end, `git --exec-path` was wrong (see my last comment to @torek's answer above). I tried to fix that with environment variables but couldn't get it working, so I ended up building from source and installing that way.