# Using Git Bash under WSL

Tags: git, git-bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to use Git Bash (instead of the native Linux `git`) under `WSL`.

```
$ type git.exe
git.exe is hashed (/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git.exe)
```

The trouble is, I'm getting:

```
$ git.exe alias list
git: 'alias' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

From [Expansion of alias failed; not a git command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60611612/), it seems that I need to override

`git --exec-path`

But having done

`export GIT_EXEC_PATH='/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core'`

The `git --exec-path` output is still the same as before:

```
$ git --exec-path
C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
```

How to override `git --exec-path`, or make the `git alias` work?

PS. the reason that I need to use Git Bash instead of the native Linux `git` is that the latter gives me:

```
$ git pull
fatal: Unsupported SSL backend 'schannel'. Supported SSL backends:
        gnutls
```

But I have to use schannel backend for my git to work.

*UPDATE:*

Just want to point out that all the recommended solutions are not the answer to this specific question, and hopefully such note *"will help prevent your question from getting closed and will remove the suggested questions notification from your post"*. *Thank you all though, for all the answers so far*

Comment: Probably better fix the real `git` instead. Perhaps see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742607/switch-to-native-windows-secure-channel-library-from-openssl-library-on-wind

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch to "Native Windows Secure Channel library" from "OpenSSL library" on Windows Git, without reinstalling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45742607/switch-to-native-windows-secure-channel-library-from-openssl-library-on-wind)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> $ git pull
>   fatal: Unsupported SSL backend 'schannel'. Supported SSL backends:
>          gnutls
> ```

As I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53137619/6309), try in your WSL session, with the Linux Git:

```
git config --global http.sslBackend openssl
```

make sure that `git version` is 2.20 or more.

Comment: setting http.sslBackend to "openssl" will allow Git for Windows to choose the SSL backend at runtime. Will it work for Linux Git as well? My git version is 2.20.1, why it says "Supported SSL backends: gnutls" without mentioning "openssl"?

Comment: @xpt Upgrading Git (the Linux one) would be a good idea (to 2.29.2). If it can choose its SSL backend at runtime, it should pick gnutls.

Comment: Honestly, I think that's the wrong direction, as I believe git-bash, i.e., Git for Windows, has many specific tweaks to make it works with schannel backend. Normal git would not work. As a proof, I've tried the git under mysys2, and it is not working for my case -- MS TFS/git server.

Comment: @xpt OK. I usually uses Git for Windows or Linux Git (WSL).

Comment: @Mark What version of Git are you using, with which OS?

Comment: @VonC git is already the newest version (1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3). using WSL2 with Ubuntu

Comment: @Mark 2.25? That is old ;) (2.30 would be the latest, but would need to be compiled for that Ubuntu distribution). Can you ask a separate question illustrating your issue?