# Hyper terminal issue ubuntu

Tags: git-bash, hyper

I have installed hyper through command line. After installing I tried to configure it. after that whenever I'm trying to launch the hyper, it is opening with the following in the screen:
**execvp(3) failed.: No such file or directory**
How to solve it?
I ave uninstalled and reinstalled it still the same.
However I have not installed git-bash. How to install git-bash in ubuntu 20.04 lts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have seen, this is followed by [`vercel/hyper` issue 3703](https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/3703)

It is related to the `.hyper.js` content

Note that "git-bash" is a term related to [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).
On Ubuntu, there would not be a git-bash, just a bash with Git in its PATH.
On Ubuntu, you can [install Git, if missing, with ppa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying about Git and hyper follow up. I will wait for the solution about hyper.

Answer (score 0):

I think you changed the default configuration of hyper. Here is the default content. Just copy and paste it into the *.hyper.js* file.
https://gist.github.com/anandb0101/a4f4201a299ae17230446361b986b0ab