# .gitconfig not working even if i've configured correctly

Tags: git

I've configured `~/.gitconfig` correctly as below.

```
git config --global user.name "yuzhi"
git config --global user.email "1762266120@qq.com"
```

Here is the result.

```
saber@debian:~$ git config -l
user.name=yuzhi
user.email=1762266120@qq.com
core.editor=vim
color.ui=true

saber@debian:~$ git config --global -l
user.name=yuzhi
user.email=1762266120@qq.com
core.editor=vim
color.ui=true
```

What confuses me is that it does not work when i `git commit`.

```
saber@debian:~/ics2020$ sudo git commit

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'root@debian.(none)')
```

But it works when i issue `git commit` after the commands below.

```
git config --local user.name "yuzhi"
git config --local user.email "1762266120@qq.com"
```

BTW:
i'm running `Debian-10.8` on the vmware.
and  `git==2.20.1`.
[here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Sourcetree-questions/git-global-config-not-working/qaq-p/297406) is the similar question as mine, but i don't know how to solve in linux.

Comment: When you use `sudo`, the local user is not `saber`. The sudo user has its own global configuration. As the log says, the sudo user is `root`. You could use  `git config --system` if all the users belong to you only.

Comment: Also worth to mention - you should never have to use `git` commands as `sudo`. If so, you've done something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare (assuming a recent enough Git, if not: [update it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309)) configuration with:

```
git config --show-origin --show-scope -l
sudo git config --show-origin --show-scope -l
```

You will clearly see the difference in paths (`/home/saber/` vs. `/root`), explaining why you don't see the same configuration.
That being said, as commented, don't use `sudo` for regular commands like `git`.

---

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667422/gitconfig-not-working-even-if-ive-configured-correctly?noredirect=1#comment117854646_66667864), if the repository was initially created with `sudo` (generating files owned by `root`), the first commit (done with the regular user) will trigger:

```
saber@debian:~/ics2020$ git commit 
fatal: Unable to create '/home/saber/ics2020/.git/index.lock': Permission denied.
```

That means you need to restore the proper ownership:

```
cd ~/ics2020
sudo chown -R $(id -u saber):$(id -g saber)
```

Then a simple commit (*without* `sudo`) will work.

Comment: You're Right!!! Thanks so much!
But it gets me a little bit confused about the option `--show-scope`.

`
saber@debian:~/ics2020$ git config --show-origin --show-scope -l
error: unknown option show-scope
`
Therefore, i remove it and issue
`
git config --show-origin -l
sudo config --show-origin -l
`
the first cammond shows
`
file:/home/saber/.gitconfig     user.name=yuzhi
file:/home/saber/.gitconfig     user.email=1762266120@qq.com
`
but the output of the second has no user.name and user.email...

Comment: @Arthur `--show-scope` means Git 2.26 minimum (Q1 2020: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60286340/6309). You can update git with ppa: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309.

Comment: anothor question:
when issue `git commit`,it shows 
`saber@debian:~/ics2020$ git commit
fatal: Unable to create '/home/saber/ics2020/.git/index.lock': Permission denied`.
it needs `sudo`... so i solve it as below.
`saber@debian:~/ics2020$ sudo git config --global user.name "yuzhi"
saber@debian:~/ics2020$ sudo git config --global user.email "1762266120@qq.com"
saber@debian:~/ics2020$ sudo git config --global core.editor vim
saber@debian:~/ics2020$ sudo git config --global color.ui true`

i don't know why i asked to execute it as `sudo`！

Comment: @Arthur Probably because the repository was initially created with `sudo`, with files owned by `root`. Use `sudo` to restore the proper ownership: `cd /path/to/repo; sudo chown -R $(id -u saber):$(id -g saber)`. Then try to commit again (*without* `sudo`)

Comment: @Arthur Great! I have edited the answer to reflect that error and its resolution, for more visibility.