# Why there is error coming while creating branch through terminal in VS code for my migration

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, zsh

`git checkout -b<sd_6153_update_mapfre_bop_question>`

By giving this command to create branch and switch to it, I am getting this o/p.

I don't have idea why this is happening:

```
zsh: parse error near `\n'
```

Comment: It's because you used `>` without a file name. You would have gotten a different error if you wrote `git checkout -b <sd_6153_update_mapfre_bop_question` without having a file named `sd_6153_update_mapfre_bop_question`, or yet another different error if that file did exist. Why did you include the `<` and `>` angle brackets in your command?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux (since zsh is involved):

- [upgrade Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309)
- go to zsh session (not in VSCode but in a separate shell outside VScode)
- test if creating a branch would work there (using the [newer command `git switch` instead of `git checkout`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309))

That is:

```sh
cd /path/to/repository
git switch -c sd_6153_update_mapfre_bop_question
```

Note: no `<` `>`, which would not be interpreted correctly by the shell.

Once that is working (confirmed by a `git status`), go back to VSCode.