# Git hub token contains invalid characters

Tags: github, access-token

I usually connect to my website's web host using a windows power shell terminal.

While trying to update composer using "`composer self-update --2`" command, I am getting the error as follows

```
Your github OAuth token for github.com contains invalid characters
```

I have checked for `auth.json` where `composer.json` file located but I could not find it.
So I tried to update the token using the command prompt but nothing worked.

I have attached the error image please check, and any help would be appreciable.

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 3):

It may depend on your composer version.

As shown in [this article](https://nono.ma/github-oauth-token-for-github-com-contains-invalid-characters-on-composer-install) by [Nono Martínez Alonso](https://twitter.com/nonoesp):

> The solution is to update Composer to the latest version, which supports the new token format, as suggested by Jordi Boggiano on [this tweet](https://twitter.com/seldaek/status/1395375090603286534).
> "Composer 1.10.21 and 2.0.12 (both released April 1st) added support for the new GitHub token format."
>
> - Go to getcomposer.org/download/
> - Follow the instructions to download the latest phar

And in your `auth.json`:

```json
 "http-basic": {
    "github.com": {
      "username": "[YOUR-GITHUB-USERNAME]",
      "password": "ghp_[YOUR-PERSONAL-TOKEN]"
    }
  }
```

---

[Alex Gusev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4073821/alex-gusev) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886290/git-hub-token-contains-invalid-characters/70890938#comment129627825_70890938):

- try to add your username & OAuth token into `~/.composer/auth.json`
- use `-n` option with `composer`: `composer -n ...`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I do not have a auth.json file. I have checked in the places where auth.json file should be. I am trying to create one using composer but it is giving that above error.

Comment: @mik OK. What version of OS, git and composer do you have?

Comment: @mik OK. Any chance you could upgrade composer to 2.2.5? And Git to 2.35.0? (throug ppa: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309)

Comment: Hi @VonC, These are the current versions The Apache version is: 2.4.52 The Ubuntu Version is: 18.04.6 composer: 1.10.12 and for git it is: 2.17.1

Comment: Hi @VonC, I have followed the details in the link you have provided, but getting the bash "bash: sudo: command not found" tried to install bash using "apt-get install sudo -y" even for that got "bash: apt-get: command not found".  even tried su - but he result is same bash. Can please give me some more other possible solutions

Comment: @mik regaridng sudo, check first https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/428976/7490

Comment: try to add your username & OAuth token into `~/.composer/auth.json` as mentioned by @VonC and use -n option with composer: `composer -n ...`

Comment: @AlexGusev Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

github changed their [token format](https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/) and composer checks the format before calling out to github via regexp. Older versions of composer won't recognize the new token format. Updating composer will fix the issue:

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: ... the question is how can you update when `composer self-update` is failing with an error. So obviously that can't be the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing will be fixed until you will not run the `composer self-update' command into the parent directory of your server. Into the project, root composer will always be failed in this specific case.

Composer Path:
`/usr/local/bin`

AuthJson Path:
`/opt/bitnami/php/composer/auth.json`