Invalid GitHub OAuth Token Error During Laravel Installation via Composer
I wanted to install Laravel on Windows using the following command:
composer create-project laravel/laravel example-app

However, after running the command, I encountered this error:
In BaseIO.php line 140:

  Your GitHub OAuth token for github.com contains invalid characters: "صثقففعععغعلغغل555656"
create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]

What’s causing this error? How can I fix it?
Could this be related to GitHub’s authentication changes? I enabled GitHub’s two-factor authentication just today. I believe this token is a random and incorrect user with invalid characters shown in the error.
Composer version: 2.7.9 (updated)

https://www.google.com/search?q=Your+GitHub+OAuth+token+for+github.com+contains+invalid+characters delivers some hits, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70886290/git-hub-token-contains-invalid-characters may be relevant here.

I have already done this search before, but I didn’t get a positive result, and my problem is still unresolved. @tevemadar

"How can I fix it?" - did you check the token for possibly invalid characters? Everything following the digits looks invalid to me

This is how I solved the problem. First, I ran the following command:
$ composer global about
------------------------------
Changed current directory to C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Composer - Dependency Manager for PHP - version 2.7.9
Composer is a dependency manager tracking local dependencies of your projects and libraries.
See https://getcomposer.org/ for more information.

Then according to the Composer path, I entered the Composer directory and opened the auth.json file.
In this file, I encountered the following configuration and realized that the wrong token was set here:
{
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "صثقففعععغعلغغل555656"
    }
}

Finally, I replaced the token that I had created in my GitHub account and the problem was solved.

sometime face this problem but it's solve very easy
1st step
1.composer config --global --unset github-oauth.github.com
2.composer config --global --list
**2nd step **
1.open github>settings>Developer Settings>personal access token>token classic>generate token

generate token  cope it

3nd step
 1.go to windows search bar and search "AppData"
 2. open AppData>Roamin>Composer>auth 
 3.auth.json  delete this file

4th step
1.composer config --global github-oauth.github.com < past your-new-token>
5th step
composer create-project laravel/laravel xyz

 

