# How to re-install with specific git version on Ubuntu?

Tags: git

How to (re)install with specific git version on Ubuntu ?

I need v2.39.1

I have
$ git --version
git version 2.25.1

Is there any update mechanism or just re installation of the packet

Answer (score 1):

I would normally only do a [ppa upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install git
```

The [`git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa`](https://launchpad.net/%7Egit-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) does reference the v2.39.1 in its latest version.

But if you need to install a *specific* version, which would not be the latest one, then it would be:

```
sudo apt install git=1:2.x.y-1~ppa0~ubuntu23.04.1
```