# How to use git interactive rebase to reorder merge commit relative to other commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I am sitting in a branch which has an unpublished merge commit followed by numerous other local commits not related to it. I want to move that commit relative to some of these commits:

Unfortunately, when I do this:

```
git rebase -i <sha-of-merge-commit>^
```

instead of getting just one line like `pick <sha-of-merge-commit>` that I could reposition, the interactive rebase expands all the individual commits from the merge, of which there are almost thirty. There is a `pick` line for all of them in the rebase TODO buffer, and `<sha-of-merge-commit>` does not appear in the TODO.

How do we get `git rebase -i` to treat the merge commit as ordinary, and not bring in the commits from the second parent?

Answer (score 2):

> Looks like this is what the `--preserve-merges` of rebase does

Actually, Git 2.22, Q2 2019, actually [*deprecates* `--preserve-merge`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa1b86e45743fd5895c33adcd3769782e608bb40), and Git 2.25, Q1 2020, [stops advertising it in the "`git rebase --help`" output](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c51181ffb178a6581ecb471091cbd2d0c48f165).

I presented the more recent [`--rebase-merges` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--r) (Git 2.18, Q2 2018) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309).

```bash
# Start interactive rebase with merge commits being treated as one
git rebase -i --rebase-merges <sha-of-merge-commit>^

# The interactive rebase to-do list will open in your editor.
# Move the merge commit to the desired position relative to other commits.
# Save and exit the editor to apply the reordering.
```

---

As noted [by j6t](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6868543/j6t) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77392409/how-to-use-git-interactive-rebase-to-reorder-merge-commit-relative-to-other-comm/77429227?noredirect=1#comment136504041_77429227):

> This still list all the commits from the side branch.
> But if they are left untouched in the `todo` list, the history will not be linearized.

True, when you are doing an interactive rebase with the intention of reordering merge commits, Git needs to know about the commits that were part of the original merge so that it can recreate that merge accurately in the new history. If you do not change these lines in the to-do list, Git will perform the merge as it originally happened, without linearizing the history.

If you were to remove or edit the lines corresponding to the side branch commits, you would effectively be rewriting the history of that branch, which could lead to a linearized history—meaning the merge would no longer appear as a merge but as a series of individual commits.

To make sure the merge commit is preserved as a merge and the history of the merged branch is not linearized, you should leave the lines for the commits from the side branches as they are in the rebase to-do list. That way, when the rebase is executed, Git will recreate the merge with its original history intact, including the side branch's commits.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this still list all the commits from the side branch. But if they are left untouched in the todo list, the history will not be linearized.

Comment: @j6t Good point, thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, as well as some additional elements. Let me know if I misconstrued anything.

Comment: I'm accepting this. I didn't find this option because the git that I'm using in Ubuntu VM's doesn't have it yet! The documentation says that this one behaves correctly in interactive rebase. I didn't see any problem with `--preserve-merges`, but I was exercising only the simplest case.

Comment: @Kaz If possible, a [ppa-upgrade of git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309) would help. ` --rebase-merges` is not just `--preserve-merges`: it adds many improvements, described in my [2018 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50555740/6309)

Comment: @VonC This is the first time I needed this since I started using Git in 2008 or so, so I don't expect it again any time soon. Everywhere I've worked, it's been rebase workflow; we made a rare exception here to do a merge.  I've literally not typed `git merge` in 15 years until recently. Ideally that will be the last time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is what the `--preserve-merges` of `rebase` does.