# How to securely save git credentials?

Tags: git, credentials

I've been recently looking for a solution on how to securely save git credentials in **CentOS 7**.

I want to save credentials for multiple git repositories.

The solution that I come up with is to use **gnome-keyring** with any version of git. but I was experiencing some issues with it. and I found many posts saying it's not a good a solution in **Redhat 7** or **Centos 7**. and It will be deprecated.

```
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyrin
```

But this didn't work for me, an error when using git :

> error communicating with gnome-keyring-daemon

then I upgraded git the last version **2.11+** to use libsecret which seems to be more easy to use.

I have done the same thing.

```
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

And this seems to work as expected. my Question is this is a good solution to securely save git credentials ? Do you know any other solution to save git credentials on a CentOS machine?

Comment: I have follow this steps. After I fill the credential in .git-credential file, I opened it and it wasn't encrypted.

Comment: In git 2.20.1 libsecret comes with gnome, and I can just do: `git config --global credential.helper libsecret` It does not create any .git-credential file--ensure that credential-store is not enabled to avoid storing credentials in plain text, and delete the file with shred.

Answer (score 8):

> is this is a good solution to securely save git credentials ?

Yes, as I documented in "[Error when using Git credential helper with `gnome-keyring` as Sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/6309)".
`libsecret` implements [XDG Secret Service API](https://github.com/stefwalter/xdg-specs/tree/master/secret-service).

It is the current official library to use.

---

Update Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018), where the credential helper for **`libsecret`** (in `contrib/`) has been improved to allow possibly prompting the end user to unlock secrets that are currently locked (otherwise the secrets may not be loaded).

See [commit 9c109e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c109e9bbcadb21cd6f955301f81583a74f8aa8c) (03 Nov 2017) by [Dennis Kaarsemaker (`seveas`)](https://github.com/seveas).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 906329f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/906329f369e0899d619f53071f7364270f887947), 09 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `credential-libsecret`: unlock locked secrets
>
> Credentials exposed by the secret service DBUS interface may be locked.
> Setting the `SECRET_SEARCH_UNLOCK` flag will make the secret service unlock these secrets, possibly prompting the user for credentials to do so.
> Without this flag, the secret is simply not loaded.

---

Reminder: `libgnome-keyring` is specific to GNOME and is:

- deprecated since [January 2014](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2014-January/msg01585.html)
- completely removed with [Git 2.41 (Q2 2023)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/6309)

Comment: Have you tried this in a server like redhat 7 or centos 7 ? actually I'm getting an error. `** (process:11877): CRITICAL **: could not connect to Secret Service: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=147f3c2e379941d69295f33356ab3a6b --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1`

Comment: @user2841703 with which Git version? The credential helper calls https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Secret-1/Secret.Service.get_sync.html

Comment: @user2841703 and is the package libsecret installed on your CentOS 7 or redHat 7? (http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/limit/2/srodzaj/1/dl/40/search/libsecret-1.so.0%28%29%2864bit%29/field[]/1/field[]/2)

Comment: the last git version 2.11 and git-credential-libsecret

Comment: @user2841703 git-credential-libsecret is the utility which calls then gnome libsecret tool. Is libsecret properly installed?

Comment: yes libsecret and libsecret-devel are properly installed. and I had to install dbus-x11-1.6.12-11.el7.x86_64 too. I think the problem comes from dbus

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135977/discussion-between-user2841703-and-vonc).

Comment: I have follow this steps. After I fill the credential in .git-credential file, I opened it and it wasn't encrypted.

Comment: @M.Abulsoud I don't think those steps involves putting your credentials in `.git-credential`. As I was saying, a new question is best.

Comment: @vonc I open Passwords and Keys app, I found the credentials there. It seems it works.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu, I entered the path to libsecret in my .gitconfig, but libsecret isn't storing the credentials. everytime I make a commit, I have to entered again and again my credentials. Do I have to set up this flag: *SECRET_SEARCH_UNLOCK*? if so, how?

Comment: @AfonsoSchulzAlbrecht path to libsecret? That should not be needed. A simple  `git config credential.helper libsecret` is enough. Then you can check what is stored in it following https://stackoverflow.com/a/66650654/6309

Comment: I run the command `git config credential.helper libsecret` successfully, then I enter my credentials in a pull request but it seems that libsecret isn't storing them because in the following pull requests, git keeps asking my credentials. (i'm using WSL2, runs ubuntu, so it shouldn't be a problem imo)

Comment: @AfonsoSchulzAlbrecht On Ubuntu WSL2, I would recommend instead manager-core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66779565/6309 (because of dbus issue: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4254)