# Git commands ask for login, but displays https://<password>@github.com

Tags: git

When I try to pull or fetch from a repository, Git asks for my password via a new window with the title `Ksshaskpass` (KDE openSUSE).

However, it asks for the password for `https://<myPassword>@github.com` rather than `<myUsername>@github.com`.
I have a feeling that in a window previous I entered my password when it was asking for a username, but now I am unsure how to fix the account it is trying to authenticate.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an HTTPS URL, check what kind of credential helper you are using

```
git config credential.helper
```

If it is libsecret, as in `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret`, try and remove the cached credentials (with the wrong username) with:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | \
 /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret erase
```

Then try again a pull from your private repository: a popup should allow you to enteer (correctly this time) your credentials (username/password)

Comment: ```git config credential.manager``` does not return anything. It just goes to a new line in the terminal.

Comment: I meant ```credential.helper```, but didn't make the edit in time.

Comment: I ended up fixing this by just deleting the ```Ksshaskpass``` folder from ```KWalletManager```. A subsequent ```git pull``` prompted me for my username and password.